# привязка элемента к двум другим

Tags: android, дизайн

На экране два круга (картинка *png*, не *shape*), между ними стрелка. Эти изображения во время работы могут двигаться (без анимации, просто при загрузке *активити* могут по-разному стоять). Нужно, чтобы оба конца стрелки были привязаны к окружности.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Как понимать привязаны к окружности? И что такое стрелка?

Comment: в том то и дело, что я могу объяснить только визуально. привязка к окружности значит что конец стрелки должен находиться на окружности. Стрелка - символ в виде черты, к концу которой сходятся под углом два коротких отрезка. как ее реализовать - понятия не имею, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Писать кастомную view, конечно